# Distinguish between two variables in one column

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with dynamic data which will populate my Google Sheet from a Form.
Basically we work with two companies at a time who assess different client opportunities. This sheet feeds into Google Data Studio.
In order to avoid manipulating the data in the sheet each time we want to display info in Data Studio, for each client that is assessed I am trying to use a formula to attach a tag in column F. Client assessed with the number 1 for the first assessment and Client assessed with the number 2. I.e: Lloyds1 or Lloyds2.

This would be easily doable if only one person from each company assessed client account but in fact it could be two or three from each company.
In the case of one person from each company i used this:
=IF(ISBLANK($D2),,(D2&COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,D2))) - worked because there would only ever be two entries

I've tried to adapt this to COUNTIFS but it doesn't work.

Hopefully I explained this problem ok and someone can help

Link to sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10sqp0zpThdtdRws2p2Dqs0n8IwxwBIpwk-ibH5vofGQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should fix your sample spreadsheet. It contains nothing on C2 column (so you should not expect that anyone will be able to reproduce your formula). Also, it will be easier if you add a column with the desired output.

Comment: Of the spreadsheet you provided, which column do you want to be automatically filled by a formula ?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz correct, sorry moved the formula over from a different sheet. C column is in fact D in the sheet I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I couldn't do it all in one formula as the `countifs` was not working for me as well. So I had to do it in a support table (which you can put in a support tab or something where you can hide it):

The support table I did was the following:

- cell `A2`: formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(B2:B),B2:B&""&C2:C,))`
- cell `B2`: formula `=unique(E2:F)`
- cell `D2`: formula `=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B),countifs(B2:B,B2:B,row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B)),))`

And then in the cell, you want you may have the following:
`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(E2:E),,(E2:E&vlookup(E2:E&""&F2:F,A2:D,4,false))))`

It should look like this:

[image]

It is not the neatest solution, but it works and is dynamic

Comment: Thanks for the response though what I'm trying to achieve is as follows:
- the first form response assessing the client Lloyds no matter which company (ABC or Eagle) will be called Lloyds 1.
- Say for example it was ABC who assessed Lloyds, all subsequent assessments of Lloyds by ABC employees will still be tagged Lloyds1 and all assessments coming in from Eagle will tagged Lloyds2.

I'm not sure your formula takes into account the company making the assessment?

Comment: Ok what I understood from your example was that if the partner was the Partner A it would be 1, if the partner was B it would be 2, at least that was what I saw from your sheet output. will try it with your perspective

Comment: Ok I updated the answer, you have it here , it is not the neatiest solution but it works

Comment: This is great Nabais, thank you very much for the update. Looks like it works exactly as I want now 